# Python Flask : list of multiple routes or endpoints

Tags: python, flask

Using Python 3.8 and Flask, I need the server side code below to :

1) pass a list of unknown length of endpoints to app.route(),

2) ensure that they are listed as valid routes by printing the routes added.

The following code has no errors, but it does not seem to do anything.

```
# server.py
from flask import Flask 

methods = ['GET','POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS', 'PATCH']
endpoints = ['users','countries', <etc>] # <etc> to indicate list of unknown length

app = Flask(__name__)
for endpoint in endpoints:
    #print(endpoint)
    app.route('/<str:endpoint>', methods=methods)

print(app.url_map) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

`print(app.url_map)` only returns : 
`Map([<Rule '/static/<filename>' (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) -> static>])` ... which I think means that none of my listed endpoints were added!

Using the following 3 requests with the above code, only the endpoints of the first 2 would be valid:

```
'http://127.0.0.1:5000/users',
'http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries',
'http://127.0.0.1:5000/xxx'
```

*The client side code is not listed, because it's not relevant to the above question.*

Answer (score 0):

Use the `app_url_rule` method if you want to bind endpoints dynamically (i.e. not with the `app.route` decorator)

Flask doc for [app_url_rule](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule):

> ```
> @app.route('/') 
> def index():
>     pass
> ```
>
> Is equivalent to the following:
>
> ```
> def index():
>     pass 
> app.add_url_rule('/', 'index', index)
> ```
>
> If the view_func is not provided you will need to connect the endpoint
>   to a view function like so:
>
> ```
> app.view_functions['index'] = index
> ```

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it's satisfactory

Answer (score -1):

The function app.route() is a decorator. It is used to specify that a method should be called for a request to a particular resource (URI) is received. The code you have above is only generating a decorator, not actually using it to bind a function.

Here is an example of how app.route() works:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World"
```

In your code, there is no function to bind the routes to.

For example, if you wanted to bind all of the routes in your list to hello world, you could use this code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


methods = ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS', 'PATCH']
endpoints = ['users', 'countries']  # <etc> to indicate list of unknown length

for endpoint in endpoints:
    @app.route(endpoint, methods=methods)
    def hello_world():
        return "Hello World"
```

However, I'm not sure why you would need to bind the same function to an indeterminate number of resources.

Comment: The code you specified gives the following error:
`AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: hello_world`